# Function with finite solutions

Tags: analysis, limits, functions

I'm working on some very old Putnam problems (think 1955), and I found one that
I think would be interesting to tackle, but I am not sure how to go about
executing it.

Take $f : \mathbb{Z}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ to be a function such that
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n) = 0.$ I want to show that there are only
finitely many solutions to the equation $f(x) + f(y) + f(z) = 1.$ I would
imagine that this may be some form of assume for the sake of contradiction, and
thus I originally AFSOC there are infinitely many $(x,y,z) \in 
\left(\mathbb{Z}^{+}\right)^3$ such that $f(x) + f(y) + f(z) = 1.$ Let us call
this solution set $A$. We can see that $A$ is countable by being a subset of
the countable $\left(\mathbb{Z}^{+}\right)^3.$ I would really like to find
some particular $\epsilon$ that contradicts our limit statement about $f$, but
I can't seem to figure out how to go about finding this. Any suggestions?

Comment: What if $f(0)=1$ and $f(n)=0$ otherwise? Then $(0,m,m+1)$ is a solution for all $m$, so we have a counterexample.

Comment: I'm guessing $\Bbb{R}^+$ means $\Bbb{R}_{>0}$?

Comment: @Servaes OK, thanks. I thought it stands for nonnegative reals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $(x_n,y_n,z_n)$ is a sequence of solutions. Taking appropriate subsequences, we can assume each of $x_n$, $y_n$, $z_n$ is either a constant or goes to infinity. Since we have infinitely many solutions, we can assume $z_n\to\infty$.

Case 1. $x_n=X$, $y_n$ goes to infinity. We get $f(x_n)+f(y_n)+f(z_n)\to f(X)$ but $f(x_n)+f(y_n)+f(z_n)=1$, so that $f(X)=1$, which means $f(y_n)=0$. This is a contradiction because $f$ is always positive.

Case 3. $x_n=X$, $y_n=Y$. Analogous to Case 2.

Case 4. $x_n$, $y_n$, $z_n$ go to infinity. We get $f(x_n)+f(y_n)+f(z_n)\to 0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:**

> Because $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0$ there exists $N\in\Bbb{Z}^+$ such that $f(n)<\tfrac13$ for all $n>N$.

**Hint 2:**

> Every value is assumed by $f$ only finitely many times.